# Is this possible in Visual studio 2010 c++ to run different .cpp files using different buttons of Windows Form Application?

Tags: visual-c++

I am using visual studio 2010 Professional and made some **.cpp** files using **Win32 Console c++.**

All the files are under same project like for training and testing,etc.

Now is it possible that I make different buttons on windows form application to run these different .cpp files just by clicking buttons like for training,testing,etc.

I tried to do this but the error is coming because CLR is not compatible with **/MT,/MTd,**etc although I have tried to change the Properties.Also I am using VC++ in all **.cpp** files and form application produce C# code on Double clicking it.This could also be the reason of error.

Whenever I run a .cpp file I exclude all other .cpp files to build that otherwise the Build is failed.I am new to this so kindly guide me. Moreover, all **.cpp** files have their own main() function.

Comment: How is it possible to call a function on button click event..Could you guide me any link or tutorial for this?

Comment: Also how to deal with the errors coming while doing this??because the project was earlier made in Win32 Console C++ and now I am adding Window Form to it that is a CLR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not keep multiple main functions. One program should have only one entry point.
2. What do you mean by "running the .cpp files"? When a project is compiled, all the source files are by default compiled. You can "call" functions that are defined in different .cpp files.
3. As for buttons for testing, you can assign different buttons to call different functions.

I hope that solves your problem.